# How do I merge these two button functions into one, like an on/off switch

Tags: javascript, function, button, toggle, var

How can I merge these two button functions into one, so that the button will toggle from isRunning=true to isRunning=false, back again and so forth? "isRunning" is a variable in a javascript function on the page.

Also I would like to replace the standard button into an image button that I design myself (simple .jpg file). Can anyone help? See the code below:

```
<button onclick="isRunning = false">hold</button>
<button onclick="isRunning = true">continue</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
<button onclick="isRunning = !isRunning; this.innerHTML = (isRunning) ? 'hold' : 'continue'">hold</button>
```

For your image attempt:

```
<img src="hold.jpg" onclick="isRunning = !isRunning; this.src = (isRunning) ? 'hold.jpg' : 'continue.jpg'" />
```

Comment: Very nice and concise.

Comment: Yes. But the text needs to change too from "hold" to "continue" and back again as you click.

Comment: No, the text inside the button says 'click me' instead of switching from hold to continue and back again as you click.

Comment: Fixed it, works now (tested). I used innerHtml instead of innerHTML

Comment: Yep best answer of the 3.

Comment: Yes, works brilliantly! How would I replace this standard button with 2 switching button images?

Comment: make the tag img instead of button and then after 'continue' add this ; this.src = (isRunning) ? 'img1.jpb' : 'img2.jpg'

Comment: The image tag doesn't seem to do it. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="toggleButton(this)">Toggel Me</button>
```

Then

```
function toggleButton(element) {
    if(isRunning == false) {
        element.innerHTML = "TRUE";
        isRunning = true;
    } else {
        element.innerHTML = "FALSE";
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even smaller:

```
<button onclick="toggleButton()">hold</button>
```

JS:

```
function toggleButton() {
    isRunning = !isRunning;
}
```

Though you should consider not using "onclick" and instead registering a proper event handler, as suggested in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F). It allows you to separate your code from the HTML, making it easier to maintain and read. Especially when it's more than just one line of code.

Comment: You statement would be true if you were using JQuery since, as the answer illustrates, "jQuery internally uses addEventListener and attachEvent" whereas sense you are using vanilla javascript it shouldn't use such methods unless you instruct it to.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unless you instruct it to", but I changed the link to point to the MDN article that was mentioned in the SO answer, since it's not jQuery-specific

Comment: Instructed it being your function uses addEventListener and attachEvent. Which seems to be what your linked article is instructing how to do.